# CircleCI Serverless framework build fails

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, circleci

CircleCI Install Serverless CLC build suddenly fails, Have not changed anything in config file.

[image: Circle CI failed]

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
 aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@3.1
 build-tools: circleci/build-tools@3.0.0
 node: circleci/node@5.0.3
 python: circleci/python@2.1.1
 docker: circleci/docker@2.2.0
 serverless-framework: circleci/serverless-framework@2.0.0

- serverless-framework/setup
- node/install-packages
- setup_remote_docker
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest version fixed our issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by updating the serverless-framework version to `serverless-framework: circleci/serverless-framework@2.0.1`